# Passing value from vector pair of struct pointer to function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

The code is about finding diameter of a tree where nodes are connected by edges. I'm facing problem when I call the diameter function. It compiles without error, but when I run the code, the code stops its execution after calling the diameter function.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left,*right;
};

int height(struct Node* node){
    if(node==NULL) return 0;
    else return max(height(node->left),height(node->right))+1;
}
int diameter(struct Node* node){
    if(node==NULL){
       return 0;
    }
    int left_height=height(node->left);
    int right_height=height(node->right);
    return max(left_height+right_height+1,max(diameter(node->left),diameter(node->right)));

}

int main(){
    int n,t1,t2;
    cin>>n;
    vector<pair<int,int>>v;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        cin>>t1>>t2;
        v.push_back({t1,t2});
    }
    vector<pair<struct Node*,struct Node*>>v2;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        struct Node* node1=new Node,*node2=new Node;
        node1->data=v[i].first; node2->data=v[i].second;
        node1->left=NULL; node2->right=NULL;
        node1->right=node2; node2->left=node1;
        v2.push_back({node1,node2});
        // v2[i].first=node1; v2[i].second=node2;
    }
    cout<<"hei"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<(signed)v2.size();i++){
        cout<<v2[i].first->data<<" "<<v2[i].second->data<<endl;
    }
    // return 0;
    int dia=0,maxdia=0;
    for(auto it : v2){
        dia=diameter(it.first);
        if(dia>maxdia) maxdia=dia;
        dia=diameter(it.second );
        if(dia>maxdia) maxdia=dia;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"anything"<<endl;

    cout<<maxdia<<endl;
    return 0;
}

/* inputs 
//Input1
3
3 2
2 1
//Input2
5
4 2
1 4
5 4
3 4

*/
```

The diameter function works fine by manual inputs

```
struct Node* NewNode(int data){
    struct Node* node=new Node();
    node->data=data;
    node->left=NULL; node->right=NULL;
}

int main(){
    struct Node* root= NewNode(1);
    root->left=     NewNode(2);
    root->right=    NewNode(3);
    root->left->right=    NewNode(4);
    root->left->left=     NewNode(5);
    // root->right->left=    NewNode(6);
    root->left->left->right=    NewNode(7);
    root->left->right->right    =NewNode(8);
    root->left->right->right->left    =NewNode(9);
    root->left->right->right->left->right    =NewNode(10);
    cout<<diameter(root)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *It compiles without error, but...* -- Compiling without errors only means that there are no syntax errors.  The program can still have logical errors.  That's where *debugging* is done.  What debugging of the program have you done?

Comment: I am considering iterated node as root node so as to find the the maximum diameter of the tree. There is no fixed root node.

Comment: Your two examples seem to use different trees.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Initially I was getting errors while using the vector pair to store the node pointers which is solved by visiting other stack overflow questions and taking about logical errors, I have provided the manual input example which shows the diameter function is correct.

Comment: What is the test input that fails?  Also, you should take the code and debug it locally on the compiler you have.  Debugging your own code is part of learning how to write programs.  You shouldn't rely on websites and previous answers -- you should take the code, step through it with the debugger, and see for yourself where the flaws are.  Then once you see where the flaw is, then you can either fix it yourself, or give us details on the flaw you found in the logic and suggest how to address it.

Comment: @Beta Yes there are two examples at the end of the code. I have updated it to understand.

Comment: What are you doing here: `cin>>t1>>t2` ??

Comment: `cout` , `using namespace std;`, ( etc. ? ) are not `C`.  Removed `C` tag.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Initially I thought I'm doing something wrong related to C++ language.Okay I'll find the flaw myself

Comment: That is where you're mistaken.  If the code compiles without errors or warnings, all that means is that there are no errors/warnings.  It has nothing to do with whether you made a logical error.  If I were to ask you write a program to add two numbers, and instead it subtracted the numbers, the program will compile without any errors.  Is the program correct?  No.

Comment: Also [this is a better way to present the program here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1d2edcfa5f28668).  Note the use of standard headers, and the input is retrieved using `std::istringstream` instead of `cin`.

Comment: Implementation of your tree is where the flaws lies.

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
int height(struct Node* node){
    if(node==NULL) return 0;
    else return max(height(node->left),height(node->right))+1;
}
```

will go into infinite recursion if you call it on a cyclic graph, like this one:

```
...
node1->right=node2; node2->left=node1;
...
```